# Are there any Objective-C / Cocoa naming conventions for properties that are acronyms?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, naming-conventions

I have an object that models an online resource. Therefore, my object has to store the URL of the resource it belongs to. How would I name the getter and setter?

```
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];

// Set values
[myObject setURL:url];
myObject.URL = url;

// Get values
[myObject URL];
myObject.URL;
```

or would the following be better:

```
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];

// Set values
[myObject setUrl:url];
myObject.url = url;

// Get values
[myObject url];
myObject.url;
```

The former example would of course require to define the property in the following way:

```
@property (retain, getter = URL, setter = setURL:) NSURL *url;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has a list of [Acceptable Abbreviations and Acronyms](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/APIAbbreviations.html), where `URL` is listed. I use `URL` myself, consistent with `NSURLRequest`, `NSURLResponse`, `NSPersistentStore` etc (which all have a `URL` property).

I think an advantage to using uppercase names is that it works better with camelcase: `anURL` looks better than `anUrl` (in my opinion).

Comment: It may look better in an individual's opinion, but casing like "myUrl" preserves word separation properly and is therefore more clear.  While NSURL is ubiquitous enough to violate this rule without pain, its a poor choice in general.

Comment: anUrl looks better than anURL (in my opinion). Moreover, anUrl follows the way normal text is written. When you read a book, almost all words have only one capital letter at the beginning, or they consist of lower case letters only. Therefor, your brain is better trained to read series of lower case letters than to read series of upper case letters. It's probably for this reason that anURL feels very chewy for me to read while anUrl goes down more fluently.

Answer (score 1):

apple uses... both ;)

it looks like the pattern is moving towards `url`/`setURL:`

Comment: So basically a mixture of what I proposed, right? I mean, `[myObject url]` but `[myObject setURL]`. But what does that mean for the dot notation is it `myObject.url = ...` or `myObject.URL = ...`

Comment: `@property (retain, setter=setURL:) NSURL *url;` I believe will allow `obj.url = ...` or `[obj setURL:...];`.

Comment: Please no, it's `-URL` and `-setURL`.